# Showing $m/E[X_n 1_{X_n\leq m}] \rightarrow \infty$ when $ m\rightarrow \infty$

Tags: probability-theory

$X_1, X_2,\ldots$ is a sequence of non-negative iid random variables such that $P(X_n>x)>0$ for all $x>0$. How can we show that when $ m\rightarrow \infty$,
$$\frac{m}{E[X_n 1_{X_n\leq m}]} \rightarrow \infty \quad ?$$

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the $X_n$ are iid, so the quantity $E[X_n1_{\{X_n \leq m\}}]$ does not depend on $n$. So we only consider $n=1$. Let $X=X_1$.

Note that $\lim_{m \to \infty} \frac{X}{m}1_{\{X \leq m\}}=0$ almost surely, and moreover $\frac{X}{m}1_{\{X \leq m\}} \leq 1$ for all $m$.

So by the dominated convergence theorem, $$\lim_{m\to \infty} E\bigg[\frac{X}{m}1_{\{X \leq m\}}\bigg]=E[0]=0$$